# Better way to detect HAML in a generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working on a rails generator, and I want to be able to copy over the haml/erb templates depending on what the user has setup. I've tried looking at `Rails.application.config.app_generators.template_engine`, but i just seem to get an empty hash regardless if haml or erb is setup.

What I'm doing right now is:

```
file_type = 'erb'
begin
  if Haml
    file_type = 'haml'
  end
rescue NameError
end
copy_file "views/errors/internal_server_error.html.#{file_type}", "app/views/errors/internal_server_error.html.#{file_type}"
copy_file "views/errors/not_found.html.#{file_type}", "app/views/errors/not_found.html.#{file_type}"
copy_file "views/errors/unprocessable_entity.html.#{file_type}", "app/views/errors/unprocessable_entity.html.#{file_type}"
```

But that feels incredibly hacky. Is there a better way?

Comment: what you exactly want? you want to make haml as a default view generator so that when you scaffold it will generate the html.haml instead of html.erb and also convert your existing erb's to haml ?

Comment: I have static files of the views already, I want to only copy over said format based on what template engine is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out. With haml, it sets the template_engine on the options to :haml. Inside the generator, I was able to access that value like so:

```
Rails::Generators.options[:rails][:template_engine]
```

Can see how I used it here: https://github.com/agmcleod/mosaic-errors/blob/95dff6fb8140b74e636d1dee0f6bf023a50706c6/lib/generators/errors_generator.rb